# No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'IEnumerable`1' from content with media type 'text/html'

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I have created a web api and a mvc application to consume the api. In my mvc employee controller class i have written code to consume web api. But it throws an exception when i run the application stating that,'**An exception of type 'System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException' occurred in System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information:
 No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'IEnumerable`1' from content with media type 'text/html'.**
Below is the mvc application controller class code.

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

                IEnumerable<mvcEmployeeModel> emplist;
                HttpResponseMessage response = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.GetAsync("Employee").Result;
                emplist =response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<mvcEmployeeModel>>().Result;// gets exception here
                return View(emplist);



        }
    }
}
```

Please help with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

change the Content-Type: to '`application/json`' or Content-Type:'`application/xml`'

```
Content-Type:'application/json'
```

or

```
Content-Type:'application/xml'
```